# Interpreting binomial test results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

I'm relatively new to stats and any help would be appreciated.

My experiment has two boxes one baited with food and the other non-baited. I am trying to test whether the probability of the animal successfully choosing the baited box is only by chance, i.e. 50% of the time.

Therefore my
Alternative Hypothesis= success at choosing the box= 50%
Null Hypothesis= success < 50%  / success > 50%

I have used a binomial test

```
binom.test(42, 74, p=0.5, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)
```

```
Output:
data:  42 and 74
number of successes = 42, number of trials = 74, p-value = 0.2954
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4472142 0.6823437
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.5675676
```

My questions

1. Would the binomial test be the best test to run?
2. How do I interpret the output?
   Since the p-value is 0.29 I fail to reject the null hypothesis which means that the success of choosing the baited box is not happening by chance? However given that these are experiments and I'm never going to get an exact 50% success, how should I frame my question?

Also the probability of success is only 56% which isn't vastly different from 50%- therefore how can I interpret this?

Comment: Your null and alternative hypotheses look as if they may be the wrong way round

Comment: You are testing $H_0: p = .5$ against $H_a: p \ne .5$ Your fraction of Successes $42/74 = 0.567567$ is different from $0.5,$ but not sufficiently different to Reject $H_0$ at the 5% level because P-value $0.2954 > 0.05 = 5\%.$ Alternatively, you cannot say there is a significant difference from $0.5$ because the 95% confidence interval $(.447, .682)$ contains $0.5.$ // [(+1) to both Comment and Answer of @cdalitz.]

Comment: By contrast, if you had **46** successes out of 74, then you would reject $H_0.$ Notice that R code `binom.test(46,74)$p.val` returns P-value $0.04739298 < 0.05.$

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. Just to clarify if I am assuming that the animal cannot smell the food in the baited box then should I not be testing Ha : p = .5? That both the baited and unbaited box will have a 50% chance of being selected?

Answer (score 1):

In hypothesis testing, the null hypthesis $H_0$ is usually the *opposite* of what you want to demonstrate. In your case, this means that $H_0$ is that the probability is 0.5.

`binom.text` is the correct way to test this, and the resulting p-value shows that your observation is not very unlikely under the null hypothesis. There is thus no significant deviation from $p=0.5$ whatever confidence level you might choose.

To actually achieve a significant difference, you must collect more data.

Note that `binom.test` also yields a confidence interval, which might be of more interest to you: it says in what range the probability presumably lies and you thus obtain a measurement of the *strength* of the effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! It helps clarify things